# how can i stop on_enter method in kivymd to stop duplicating list

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

***emphasized text***

```
**class HomePage(MDScreen):
         profile_pics = StringProperty("")
         balance = StringProperty("")

        def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.list_status()
        self.list_post()
        self.get_all_info()

    def list_status(self):
        with open("asset/data/store.json") as f_obj:
            data = json.load(f_obj)
            for name in data:
                self.ids.storyline.add_widget(CircularAvatarImage(
                    avatar=data[name]['avatar'],
                    name=name
                ))**
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want list_status() to be called only once.

You could add a guard statement around the list_status() call and use a class instance attribute to track state.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.list_status_needed = True

def on_enter(self, *args):
    if self.list_status_needed:
        self.list_status_needed = False
        self.list_status()
    self.list_post()
    self.get_all_info()
```